# How to use date difference as a filter

Tags: sql, oracle

I write this query:

```
select A.purchase_date, B.purchase_date
from table A
inner join table B on A.person_ID=B.person_ID
WHERE to_date(A.purchase_date) - to_date(B.purchase_date) < 3
```

In other words, I self-join a table.
However In the results, I see the purchase_date are NOT within 3 days.

Could you help?

Comment: you need to edit the question and post a [mcve] including all table DDL, sample data, and output you are seeing.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: Post a reproducible test case.  My guess is that your calculation returns a negative number for the rows you are concerned about.  You either want to specify that the difference is between 0 and 3 or you want to specify that `a.purchase_date > b.purchase_date`.  If `purchase_date` is a date, it makes no sense to call `to_date` on it.  Potentially you want to `trunc` it to remove the time component and ensure that you get an integer difference.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `TO_DATE` on columns that are already dates; at best this will do nothing, at worst your will truncate your dates changing the time component to midnight (which may or may not be your intention - if it is then use `TRUNC` and not `TO_DATE`).
2. You put an upper-bound on the difference between dates but you do not put a lower-bound on the difference if two rows `DATE '2023-01-01'` and `DATE '2023-01-10'` then `DATE '2023-01-10' - DATE '2023-01-01'` is 9 and would be filtered out but `DATE '2023-01-01' - DATE '2023-01-10'` is -9 and would not be filtered out so you will find that all rows are matched.

If you want dates that are within 72 hours (exclusive) then you can use:

```sql
SELECT A.purchase_date, B.purchase_date
FROM   table A
       inner join table B
       on A.person_ID=B.person_ID
WHERE  B.purchase_date - 3 < A.purchase_date
AND    A.purchase_date < B.purchase_date + 3
```

If you want to only compare the date components and be within 3 days then:

```sql
SELECT A.purchase_date, B.purchase_date
FROM   table A
       inner join table B
       on A.person_ID=B.person_ID
WHERE  TRUNC(B.purchase_date) - 3 <= A.purchase_date
AND    A.purchase_date < TRUNC(B.purchase_date) + 4
```

Comment: Try with abs() function .In  your case in where clause try abs(A.purchase_date, B.purchase_date)) < 3.Main use of abs function is to take absolute values of the difference.Hope this help.

Comment: @havin I considered the `ABS` function and decided that it was probably not worth using as Oracle cannot apply an index to a column when you wrap it in a function (you would need a separate function-based index and cannot do that with columns from both sides of a self-join). Doing it the way I have done may allow Oracle to use an index (you would need to check the `EXPLAIN PLAN` and confirm that though).